# How can I config one user has ReadOnly access and another user have full access to Hangfire Dashboard?

Tags: hangfire

How can I config one user has ReadOnly access and another user have full access to Dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DashboardOptions and AuthorizationFilter to set up the Read-Only and Edit access. [See Documentation from Hangfire](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html#configuring-authorization)

```
public class HangFireAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
    {
        string user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        var adminAuthz = InternalMethod.lookup_db_for_user_access(user, "View");

        return adminAuthz != null;
    }

    public bool IsUserAuthorizedToEditHangfireDashboard([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
    {
        string user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        var adminAuthz = InternalMethod.lookup_db_for_user_access(user, "Edit");

        return adminAuthz != null;
    }
}
```

Use the above filter in your Hangfire Dashboard initialization

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var hangfireAuthz = new HangFireAuthorizationFilter();
    var dashboardOptions = new DashboardOptions
    {
        Authorization = new[] { hangfireAuthz },
        IsReadOnlyFunc = (DashboardContext context) => !hangfireAuthz.IsUserAuthorizedToEditHangfireDashboard(context)
    };

    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", dashboardOptions);
}
```